# How to get first number from array and do action on it

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am generating few random numbers 4 at the start, then if user select next option (level) its 5 and so on... I am looking on how to check what the first generated number in the array is and perform an action, then after that action is done move onto second number in the array and so on.
The numbers generated are always 1 to 4 but the amount of them changes.

```
ImageButton 1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton 2= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton 3= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton 4= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
```

↑ These are the Image buttons I want to highlight depending on the first number in the array 
So lets say that the 4 numbers generated are [2,1,2,4]
I want

```
2.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7D0000);  
1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF000);
2.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7D0000);
4.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF);
```

I want the above to be change color for 1 second then move onto next color in the array.

Here's where the numbers are generated and where the code should go

```
int value;
        TextView textTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTesting);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        int[] NumbersArray = new int[20];

        for (int num = 0; num < 4 +temp; num++) 
{
            value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);

            builder.append(value + " ");
            textTest.setText(builder.toString());
            NumbersArray[num] = value;
            System.out.println(NumbersArray[num]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

numerical values are not valid variable names,

```
 ImageButton 1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

is invalid.

try this:

```
ArrayList<ImageButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();


//adds R.id.imageButton1 at first position of your list
listOfButtons.add((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1));

//adds R.id.imageButton5 at second position of your list
listOfButtons.add((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5));

//adds R.id.imageButton3 at thirdposition of your list
listOfButtons.add((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3));


//firstItem is R.id.imageButton1
ImageButton firstItem = listOfButtons.get(0);

//secondItem is R.id.imageButton5
ImageButton secondItem = listOfButtons.get(1);
....
int index;//index should never exceed list size
....
ImageButton selectedByIndex = listOfButtons.get(index);
```

Comment: Sorry about the numerical values. I have them as text in my code, but still the code you mentioned above doesn't work for me, I get errors for `index` and I get error for `selectedByIndex` as well as in ... `= new ArrayList<ImageButton>`

Comment: that was getting you the idea of what to do. obviously index is not initialized in my example and I don't know which index you wanna retrieve. if you want first element index=0; if you want second element index=1, if you want last element index=listOfButtons.size()-1;   also for arraylists to work you obviously need import java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: I imported ArrayList but I have no Idea how and where to put your suggestion into my code. I've been doing android java for past 3 weeks and have very little idea on how to achieve what I want to do. Could you please show me based on my code above on how to change the colours of the buttons depending on what numbers are in the array,

Comment: i don't exactly know what you want to do and I can't write your entire code for you neither. Actually that is not what SO is for. what I am doing here is showing you how to utilize an ArrayList that will allow you store arbitrary number of arbitrary type element (in your case ImageButton) and have random access to any index you want later.  this will eliminate the need for you to declare a ridiculous number of variables at compile time or an array that will possibly run out of space.

Comment: since you are new I will add some detail to my answer to help you out.on this website you should pick a best answer when you receive them.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helps a lot. Could you clarify where do I use that `firstItem` variable? as well as `selectedByIndex`. I figured out the other ones now I'm just stuck at these